# Visual Studio 2017 stalls during build phase of publish to Azure WebApp

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish

When publishing a project to my Azure WebApp instance the process regularly stalls in the middle of the build.  Visual Studio is responsive and I can continue to work, but the build process in the Output window is stopped at a random line, usually after a "1 File(s) copied" status, but not always on the same dll.

Waiting does nothing, I have left it overnight once to see what happens, but nothing does.  I can break the build process and re-try, and after a random number of retries it will eventually work(Sometimes twice, sometimes it takes ten attempts).

I can see nothing in the output window that is erroring, and event viewer is clean of errors and warnings.

Running a regular Build or Re-Build process without the publish works absolutely fine every time.

Comment: Try bumping the [log verbosity up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-save-and-configure-build-log-files?view=vs-2017#to-change-the-amount-of-information-included-in-the-build-log). File lock errors are fairly common IME when deploying to app services in general.

Comment: @Svend I increased it and had a look, and there was a file lock due to me using xcopy to move DLL's into a shared component library.  But it automatically retried the copy a second later, the copy was successful.  Removing the xcopy command fixes the error, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Could you post the log somewhere? There's almost always something in the log. If not, I'd look elsewhere (windows event log, or dig around in [kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service)).

Comment: Event log is empty at the time, and it doesn't even start to touch Azure(Fiddler confirms this).  Detailed Pastebin is here. https://pastebin.com/JBWqer2r

Comment: I dont spot anything obvious in the logs. You can try publishing using msbuild in a developer console, see if that yields any clues. `msbuild MySolution.sln /p:PublishProfile=name.pubxml /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" p:DeployOnBuild=True` I'm just tossing out ideas here btw ;-)

Comment: Hey @Svend Just wanted to say thanks, going to delete this question shortly.  I've got no solution and the full logs which probably contain the answer are just too long to decypher.  I'm now running a custom script to upload all the sites and webjobs after build, I guess I'm just not allowed to publish direct anymore ;)

Comment: Sometimes that happens. Azure is very beta and breaks pretty often :(